# Why data.table is not being printed sometimes in Console in RStudio?

Tags: r, data.table

I found that often when I try to print in console a `data.table` (eg. by typing `dt` and pressing Enter), it will not print anything. So I have to type it two or three times (like `dt;dt;dt`) and then it will get printed.

Not a big deal, but I' curious why it happens?
Is that me not doing something right, or is it a glitch in `data.table` package?

Sorry,  I can't make reprex - as this situation does not seem to occur deterministically. But
It often happens after in a series of mortifications made to data.table (e.f. `dt[, a:=b+c][, aa:=2*a]`)

Answer (score 7):

It is a known issue and can be solved by adding an extra `[]` at the end, e.g. `dt[, a:=b+c][, aa:=2*a][]`.

From the [data.table FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html):

> #### Why do I have to type `DT` sometimes twice after using `:=` to print the result to console?

> This is an unfortunate downside to get [#869](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/869) to work. If a `:=` is used inside a function with no `DT[]` before the end of the function, then the next time `DT` is typed at the prompt, nothing will be printed. A repeated `DT` will print. To avoid this: include a `DT[]` after the last `:=` in your function. If that is not possible (e.g., it's not a function you can change) then `print(DT)` and `DT[]` at the prompt are guaranteed to print. As before, adding an extra `[]` on the end of `:=` query is a recommended idiom to update and then print; e.g.> `DT[,foo:=3L][]`.